# Common code between javascript and controllers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a set of colors which are accessed by both my controllers and javascript files

```
colors = ["#66c2a5", "#abdda4", "#abdda4", "#fee08b", "#fd8d3c", "#d53e4f"]      
red = ["#FFF", "#d53e4f"]  
special =  ["#d53e4f", "#d53e4f", "66c2a5", "#e0e0e0"]
```

Right now I have this duplicated twice in a common javascript file and a common controller.

Is there a way to make this more neat and put it in one place only?

EDIT: I have two kinds of charts (d3.js), some are fixed and will never change and some are dynamic coming from a controller.

Those colors are common to both kinds of charts.

Is it better to put the colors in a common controller helper and pass them to JS or should I just keep things the way they are (colors in js and in controller)

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but in general, you don't want code that handles presentation in your controller. Can you explain what you're trying to do and show some code?

Comment: I agree you're right. I have fixed charts in JS and with those colors and I also have dynamic charts generated from my controllers (the parameters (colors and data) are passed to javascript).

Comment: maybe I'll just put them in a helper and pass them to JS for both types of charts ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not much of a duplication if you are using it in two different languages.

If it was a lot bigger for some reason, the only thing that comes to my mind is to have them in a controller, and make a AJAX call to ruby:

You can put them in a hash:

```
all_colors = 
     { colors: ["#66c2a5", "#abdda4", "#abdda4", "#fee08b", "#fd8d3c", "#d53e4f"],
       red: ["#FFF", "#d53e4f"], 
       special: ["#d53e4f", "#d53e4f", "66c2a5", "#e0e0e0"] 
     }
```

Then you can render them out as a json in a controller action:

```
render json: all_colors
```

But then you also have to write the javascript AJAX part, and that would be to complicated, and you would make more HTTP requests to your server.

I don't know any other way.

I suggest you leave it like this.